# Searching for a key in python dictionary using "If key in dict:" seemingly not working

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm iterating through a csv file and checking whether a column is present as a key in a dictionary.

This is an example row in the CSV file

```
833050,1,109,B147599,162560,0
```

I'm checking whether the 5th column is a key in this dictionary

```
{162560: True, 165121: True, 162562: True, 153098: True, 168336: True}
```

I pass in this dict. as the var. mt_budgets in the following code

```
def check(self, mt_budgets):
    present = {}
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    path = cwd 
    with open(path + 'file.csv.part') as f:
        csv_f = csv.reader(f)
        for row in csv_f:
            if row[4] == '162560':
                print 'Yes STRING'
                if str(row[4]) in mt_budgets:
                    print 'Yes it\'s here'
                    present[row[4]] = True
                else:
                    print 'No it\'s not'
                    print row[4]
                    print mt_budgets
```

This is the output I'm getting

```
Yes STRING
No it's not
162560
{162560: True, 165121: True, 162562: True, 153098: True, 168336: True}
```

I'm not sure why it's not picking it up as a key, what's going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of the keys of the dictionary?

Comment: `if '162560' in row[4]:`? Once the dictionary has been saved to a file, it is no longer a dictionary.  You may consider researching `json.loads()`.

Comment: You can try using with `Pandas` for csv, may be it will be easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{162560: True} # {int:bool}
{'162560': True} # {str:bool}
```

So, `mt_budgets` does not contain `'162560'` (str), it contains `162560` (int)

Your code should be:

```
def check(self, mt_budgets):
    present = {}
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    path = cwd 
    with open(path + 'file.csv.part') as f:
        csv_f = csv.reader(f)
        for row in csv_f:
            if int(row[4]) == 162560:  # csv data is possibly str format. convert it to int and compare.
                print 'Yes STRING'
                if int(row[4]) in mt_budgets:
                    print 'Yes it\'s here'
                    present[row[4]] = True
                else:
                    print 'No it\'s not'
                    print row[4]
                    print mt_budgets
```

Comment: For the record, unless the `dialect` used by the reader includes [`csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC), it's not "possibly str format", it's 100% guaranteed to be a `str`. With `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` it would be a `float`, which would work for the OP's case, as long as the values didn't start getting into the realm where floating point precision issues made the value not equal to the real integer value.